# Why do mean field theories neglect quantum correlations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mean-field-theory

A measure of the quantumness of correlations is given by the quantum discord as introduced by [Zurek in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105072)  for example.
But I have also read in this  [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-09699-5), wherein they use mean field theories to simulate a complex many body system, that "The simplest possible picture for the population dynamics relies **on a mean-field treatment (i.e., neglecting quantum correlations)**".
As I understand it, in the mean field treatment they use, the spin observables are replaced by their mean value $S\rightarrow \langle S\rangle$, so that we neglect the spin **fluctuations** $\delta S= S-\langle S\rangle$, and all  quantities involving these fluctuations.

Can anyone clearly explain the relationship between the two pictures ? i.e. why are the **fluctuations** neglected in mean field theories the same thing as **quantum correlations** as characterized by quantum discord?

Comment: If you replace $S_x, \, S_y$ with $\langle S_x \rangle, \, \langle S_y \rangle$, then won't such commutators as $[S_x, S_y] = i \hbar S_z$ become instead $0$, since the mean values are $c$-numbers? So it is like taking the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit. (NB: This is a guess, I don't know much about mean field methods.)